# problem in apt-get install -f

Tags: system-installation

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

```
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.13.0-37-generic
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Welcome! Please insert the text instead of an image. And please make the title and post in general more specific to your problem. And also search first, to see if this has been answered in some form already.

Comment: Why are you trying to install a new kernel by hand? Please describe what you are trying to do and change your title.

Comment: Looks like your default Grub configuration file has been modified and subsequently broken ...

Comment: There is an error in your /etc/default/grub file - at a guess, you have something like `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX =""` instead of `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` turning `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` from the LHS of a variable assignment into a command